# How to vertically center text next to absolute container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to vertically center this text next to the image to get a result like this: [image: img]

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 50%;
}

.span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <div class="container">
      <img style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/150x50"/>
      <span class="span">should be vertically centered next to image</span>
    </div>
</p>
```

**How to edit my code to center this text next to the ABSOLUTE container?**

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If img is 100% width, text will go under it. A div inside a p is not valid , what is the need of absolute positionning here ? ... There is a lot for you to learn and get familiar with about web media or this is a big joke ;) .

Answer (score -2):

Flexbox makes this pretty straight-forward. Here's a guide in case you aren't familiar: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <div class="container">
      <img style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/150x50"/>
      <span class="span">should be vertically centered next to image</span>
    </div>
</p>
```